# Set listview single item can be clicked at a time

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

This is my listview. I have used this code to get the clicked position of a row. But when I'm clicking on more than item at the same time, app crashes. This I understand why. How do I set list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE) like piece here? I'm using arraylist item position and NOT list item position. Please help.

```
public void onItemClick(int mPosition)
{
ListModel tempValues = CustomListViewValuesArr.get(mPosition);
totalWords = Integer.parseInt(tempValues.getTextWords2());
String statusBarPercentage=tempValues.getTextPercentage();

int pos = mPosition + 2;
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Find.class);
intent.putExtra("wordLength", pos); // parameters
startActivity(intent);
}
```

This the code I've written to take position from listview.

Adapter class:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {
//--------------code------------
/**
 * ****** Called when Item click in ListView ***********
 */
private class OnItemClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    private int mPosition;

    OnItemClickListener(int position) {
        mPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        MainActivity sct = (MainActivity) activity;
        sct.onItemClick(mPosition);

    }
}
//-----------code etc-----
}
```

Comment: I can't understand why  it is downvoted. I had to change my onclick method to list.setOnItemClickListener (that's why I accepted the answer). But my question was if it could have been done with checking arraylist position click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

Comment: not working becuase I'm using arraylist position and not list item position. Any idea how can I get list item position instead of arraylist???